# magento 2.3 search issue

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Product SKU based AND PRODUCT NAME SEARCH Not working properly if SKU consists of a special character like (space, dot, etc) it results not giving the exact result.

Is there any solution for this? Please give your valid comments, please...

Answer (score 0):

For getting exact result you have to enable Elastic Search, make sure only in attribute `SKU` and `Product` search is enabled, check other attributes i.e. description, etc , Search should be disabled there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  we enabled attribute level https://prnt.sc/o5us2s and Elastic Search in catalog section as per the screen shot https://prnt.sc/o5ut08 can please check is any thing missed or not in screen shot.

Comment: Please check this screenshot for `description` attribute: [https://prnt.sc/o68quw](https://prnt.sc/o68quw) and make `Use in Search` yes for Name and SKu only.
For better result, enable Elastic Search...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, We set 'Use in Search' property as "YES" to Name and SKU attributes Only , but it not gives actual result. our sku like "10SOVL-3x5.1", "10SOVL-2x3a" etc... Elastic Search 5.1 enabled and its test connection gives success message...

Comment: I faced the same issue, and am using elastic search and it is giving me exact result now, please clear cache and check again. It should be work.

Comment: Please check this screenshot aswell,, https://prnt.sc/o69i6n

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The above shared screen shot not found in the magento 2.3 admin side .. is this any 3 rd party plugin? if not please give flow to find this part from admin side?

Comment: I am using amasty elastic search as well.

Comment: We have not using any module for elastic search. is there any possibility to handle this on magento 2 core functionality?.